# find string including quotation marks using grep

Tags: grep, pattern-matching, quotes

How can I find a string which includes quotation marks with grep? I tried a backslash to escape but this doesn't work.

For example search for the string `"localStorage['api']"`.
I tried:

```
grep -r "localStorage['api']" /path
grep -r "localStorage[\'api\']" /path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your escaping is OK. The problem lies in the `[]`, that `grep` understands  as regular expressions. Thus, you need to somehow tell it to treat the string as literal. For this we have `-F`:

```
grep -F "localStorage['api']" file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello localStorage['api'] and blabla
bye
$ grep -F "localStorage['api']" a
hello localStorage['api'] and blabla
```

From `man grep`:

> **-F**, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
>   any of which is to be matched.